# Free command line image converter

Tags: command-line, images, conversion

I need a free image converter (program that converts images from one format to other) for Windows that can be used via command line parameters.
I've been searching for it for a long time, but couldn't find one.

Comment: @fixer1234 Lol... thank you sir, you are cooler than the coolest in my opinion fixer man. I could definitely do more thorough reading of all the policies, etc. for sure though to become more informed. I appreciate you sir as usual!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) would appear to fit the bill:

> The functionality of ImageMagick is typically utilized from the command line or you can use the features from programs written in your favorite programming language.

and it's available for Windows, Mac OSX and Unix/Lunix operating systems.

Comment: Convert  - this is the command line tool, which is part of the core ImageMagick suite of tools.

Answer (score 5):

[GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) is an old fork of ImageMagick that has active development and much less bloat / dependencies.

Comment: Still active in 2020, There is a windows installer so it's more easy to setup than the regular imagemagick.