# Command line tool for image conversion

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-tool

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free command line image converter](https://superuser.com/questions/183208/free-command-line-image-converter)

I need a command line tool for windows which can be used to convert an image from any common format to 24 bit bitmap. I'm writing some programs to do image manipulation in C, but I don't really want to write a ton of code to read images in multitudes of formats. I use bitmap format a lot for both reading and writing because it's pretty straight forward. I don't really want to convert all of the images by opening in paint and saving in the desired format.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ImageMagick can do format conversions with a tool that comes with it called `convert`. You can [find binaries for it here](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php).

You'll want to run something like this on Windows:

```
for %%f in (*.jpg) do (
       convert "%%~nf.jpg" -type truecolor "%%~nf.bmp"
)
```

Or in Bash:

```
for f in *.jpg; do convert "$f" -type truecolor "${f%.*}.bmp"; done
```

Convert picks the format automatically from the extension and `-type truecolor` makes sure you are converting to 24-bit.

Comment: What shell is your syntax for?

Comment: It doesn't look like bash, so here's the above in bash: `for f in *.jpg; do convert "$f" -type truecolor "${f%.*}.bmp"; done`

Comment: The posted code is MS batch.

Comment: It should work as a windows batch script, since that's what Big Endian is running. It is however, untested, as I do not have a windows installation.

Comment: @zmode : How I can do if I have color images and black and white images in the same directory *(scanned documents)*? Since this is for sending in a mail' I fear getting larger images for black and white ones *(1 bit for color)* by adding colorfull informations *(eg : switching from 1 bit to three bytes RGB per pixel)*. So, is it possible to to convert the format without converting color images to black and white or vice versa?

Comment: Just to amend, the [docs](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#output) clarify that it will pick the format from binary signatures first (as it should), and _then_ the extension.

Comment: While installing ImageMagick, I marked the checkbox `Install legacy tools like convert`. Also, I had to use the complete path for convert to make it work: `"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16-HDRI\convert.exe"`

Answer (score 5):

Try [Convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php). It can do a lot.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking for. 8 minutes before I can accept answer.

Comment: zmode gave more specific details, so I'm accepting his answer. Thanks!

Comment: @galuano1 :
Your link is dead.

Comment: @user2284570 Updated the link.